# Error font in vBulletin when show data from other database

Tags: vbulletin

I have a website A using database (charset utf-8) and a forum F (vBulletin 3.84) for this website.
I wrote a plugin to show some information from database website A. When I active plugin, it error font like:

```
Cao su ??ng Th�p: Chi?n l??c n�o cho t??ng lai?
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify encoding after the connection to the database. Like this:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```